# output data not printing quite as planned

Tags: csv, python-3.x, tkinter, stdout

I have a piece of code that takes an entered number, searches a CSV and outputs that line, however the original entered number is also printed. What would I need to modify in my code to remove this ?

```
    def DoASearch():
        self.outputQty.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.outputDesc.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="normal")
        self.dwgoutputbox.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")
        try:
            print(int(sonumber.get()))
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("OPPS !!", "Please enter a valid Shop Order number.")

        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    print(row['Part Number'])
                    print(row['Description'])
                    print(row['Quantity'])
                    print(row['Drawings'])
                    print(row['Issue'])

    self.searchbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Search", command=DoASearch)
    self.searchbutton.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
```

Modified and works nicely with the below code. Theres a few extra repeat fields that have been added which can be ignored.

```
def checkcsv():
        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    descQty=(row['Quantity'])
                    descInfo=(row['Description'])
                    descPN=(row['Part Number'])
                    descDwg1=(row['Drawings1'])
                    descIss1=(row['Issue1'])
                    descDwg2=(row['Drawings2'])
                    descIss2=(row['Issue2'])
                    descDwg3=(row['Drawings3'])
                    descIss3=(row['Issue3'])
                    self.outputQty.insert(INSERT,descQty)
                    self.outputDesc.insert(INSERT,descPN, END," ", END, descInfo)
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(INSERT, descDwg1, END, "   ", END, " Issue:  ",END,descIss1,END, "\n")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(INSERT, descDwg2, END, "   ", END, " Issue:  ",END,descIss2,END, "\n")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(INSERT, descDwg3, END, "   ", END, " Issue:  ",END,descIss3,END, "\n")
                    self.outputQty.configure(state="disabled")          
                    self.outputDesc.configure(state="disabled")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

A slightly better version using a loop follows:

```
def checkcsv():
        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    descQty=(row['Quantity'])
                    descInfo=(row['Description'])
                    descPN=(row['Part Number'])
                    for i in range(1,4):
                        descDwg=(row['Drawings'+ str(i)])
                        descIss=(row['Issue'+ str(i)])
                        self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss, "", "\n")
                    self.outputQty.insert(1.0, descQty)
                    self.outputDesc.insert(1.0, descPN, "", ": ", "", descInfo)
                    self.outputQty.configure(state="disabled")          
                    self.outputDesc.configure(state="disabled")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to change the following line

```
print(int(sonumber.get()))
```

into

```
int(sonumber.get())
```

However, you should really take a deeper look at your code in order to understand *which* things it does and *where* it does those things.